# The convergence of the sample mean of normal random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

$(X_i)_{1\leq i \leq n}$ are independent independent random variables of the same  distribution $N(m,1)$. Find the distribution of the r.v $\bar{X}_n= \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, then prove that $$\bar{X}_n \to^{a.s} m \quad E|\bar{X}_n - m|^2 \to 0$$

Using m.g.f or using this [theorem](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/node/172/), $\bar{X}_n= \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim N(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{m}{n}, \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n^2})$. For the rest, I know a lemma from real analysis stating that:

For the sequence $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, if  $X_n \to 0$, then $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} 0.$
 if $X_i \to 0$. 
How can I use the lemma or how can I prove the  second question ?

I want also to say that I am preparing for my exam and I solve questions from previous exams but I am stuck in this one.

Comment: Are you sure you want the a.s. limit of $\bar X_n$? (It's true, but not for reasons directly related to what you state.)

Comment: @kimchilover Honestly, I am not sure if it is related but this is what is written in the previous exam. The question asked to find the distribution of $\bar{X}_n$ then to prove what I wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

This is an odd question, imprecisely matched to the hints and the curriculum of the course it is associated with  The quantity  $\bar X_n$ is, according to the problem statment, already known to have distribution $N(m,1/n)$, and hence converges in distribution to the constant $m$ as $n\to\infty$, and hence in probability to $m$.

General cultural knowledge tells us that by the strong law of large numbers $\bar X_n\to m$ almost surely, without needing to know the precise distribution of $\bar X_n$.
Assuming one did *not* know the SLLN but did know that $\bar X_n\sim N(m,1/n)$ and   also the Borel-Cantelli lemma, one could argue that $\sum_{n>1} P(|\bar X_n-m|>1/\log n)<\infty$ after a Chebychev estimate and conclude that $|\bar X_n-m|>1/\log n$ happens only finitely often.

In greater detail.  Since $\bar X_n\sim N(m,m/n)$ we know $$P(|\bar X_n-m|>1/\log n)=P(|\frac Z{\sqrt n}|>\frac1{\log n})=P(|Z|> \frac{\sqrt n}{\log n}),$$ where $Z\sim N(0,1)$.  But $P(|Z|>\lambda)\le E[Z^4]/\lambda^4=3/\lambda^4$ by Chebychev's inequality (or maybe I should call it Markov's). Here we use the fact that the $4$th moment of $Z$ is $3$; that it is
finite is what's really important. So 
$$\sum_n P(|\bar X_n-m|>1/\log n)\le 3\sum_n \frac {(\log n)^4}{ n^2}<\infty.$$
By the [Borel-Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) this implies that with probability 1, the inequality $|\bar X_n-m|>1/\log n$ holds for only finitely many $n$. This means, with probability $1$ the inquality $|\bar X_n-m|\le 1/\log n$ holds for all $n$ sufficiently large,  which  implies $\bar X_n\to m$.  (One way to remember B-C almost surely. is to remember that a non-negative  rv with a finite expectation is finite with probability one; apply this to the sum of the indicators of the events $E_n$ mentioned in the cited wiki article.)

Comment: If I can ask for more clarification because I am kind of lost, how did you use the Chebychev and Borel-Cantelli lemma. I would be very thankful if you clarified more this part.

Comment: So you used Chebychev and Borel-Cantelli to prove the almost sure convergence for $\bar{X}_n \to m$ ? I thought previously you used them to prove $E|\bar{X}_n -m|^2 \to 0$

Comment: I am sorry for disturbing you again. I don't understand which convergence I need to study for $E|X_n - m|^2$. i.e the question asks to study the almost sure convergence in this one $\bar{X}_n \to m$ but it doesn't specify the type of convergence for this one $E|\bar{X}_n - m|^2 \to 0$?

Comment: The convergence $E|\bar X_n-m|^2\to0$ is ordinary convergence of a sequence of numbers, namely, of the variance  of $\bar X_n$.  Your problem statement already contains a formula for this variance; you should simplify it and then notice that it converges to zero.  Good luck on the exam.